# В каком слове все согласные звуки звонкие?

Tags: фонетика

Варианты ответа:
 1. Берег.
 2. Вокзал.
 3. Вулкан.
 4. Просьба.

Я был уверен, что ответ 1. Ответы гласят -2.

Почему?

Спасибо.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Вокзал -[вΛгзал]-все звонкие, потому что К озвончается перед звонкой З
2. берег - Г оглушается на конце в [К]

Comment: Т. Е. Когда глухая перед звонкий, глухая становиться звонкой?

Comment: >Когда глухая перед звонкий, глухая становиться звонкой?  
    
Не всегда. Но здесь - да.

Только не "глухая", а "глухой": **звук**.

Comment: Спасибо. Если можно, разъясните, пожалуйста, когда именно глухой звук на звонкую меняется.

Comment: отдельным ответом попробую.

Answer (score 2):

Ошибка многих - видеть буквы, а не думать о звуках. И при возникновении сомнений надо слова затранскрибировать, помня о фонетических изменениях. Тогда будет все понятно.

Comment: Совершенно верно. *Вагзал* - для двоих.

Answer (score 2):

> > Спасибо. Если можно, разъясните, пожалуйста, когда именно глухой звук на звонкую меняется.

В комментариях ответить нет никакой возможности. 
И вообще - я не бог весть какой специалист по таким вещам - надеюсь, поправят, если что

Переход глухого в звонкий под действием последующего звонкого - это проявление т.н. регрессивной ассимиляция по глухости/звонкости. Проявляется как внутри слов, так и на на стыках - при быстрой речи. 
В русском она зависит от конкретной пары глухой+звонкий. Прежде всего - от конкретного звонкого. В принципе правила вытекают из известного закона нарастающей звучности (точнее - из одного из его многочисленных следствий), но его изложить здесь во всех деталях я не рискую. Поэтому просто на конкретных случаях.

Никогда (или почти никогда?) не озвончаются глухие перед М, Н, Р, Л (группа сонорных). 
Хотя, в некоторых диалектах, кажется, возможно спорадическое озвончение глухих перед М и Н.

Обычно не озвончаются глухие перед В, но в быстрой речи и южных говорах  - возможно.

В остальных случаях - глухой перед звонким обычно озвончается. 
В принципе все "школьные" случае этим охватывается.

Дальше надо смотреть отдельные исключения (Щ, например, спорный случай) и рассматривать стечения трех и более согласных - там тоже есть тонкости. Но для Ваших примеров это неактуально.

Дальше уже надо глубоко копать.

Answer (score 2):

Информацию по этой теме, связанной с фонетическим чередованием согласных звуков, можно изложить предельно просто.

1. Фонетическое чередование касается только ПАРНЫХ звонких-глухих согласных звуков (б-п, в-ф, г-к, д-т, з-с, ж-ш) и происходит в двух слабых позициях, а именно:

а) Расположение парных согласных перед ШУМНЫМИ согласными, когда они произносятся одинаково с последующим согласным (глухо  или звонко), например: дорожка, сказка – оглушение звонких согласных Ж и З перед глухим  согласным К; сделать  – озвончение глухого согласного С перед звонким согласным Д.

б) Расположение парных согласных на КОНЦЕ слова, когда происходит оглушение парного звонкого согласного: мороз, рожь – оглушение звонких согласных З и Ж на конце слова.

1. В положении перед ГЛАСНЫМИ И СОНОРНЫМИ фонетического чередования не происходит – это сильная позиция звука. В этом случае выбор буквы для обозначения согласных делается по слуху, например:
   народы, гроза, сторожить – согласные Д, З, Ж перед гласными,
   народный, грозный, осторожно – согласные Д, З, Ж перед сонорным Н.
2. Фонетического чередования не происходит также перед В –  поэтому, например, различаются по произношению слова  зверь и сверь.

Comment: >Фонетическое чередование касается только ПАРНЫХ звонких-глухих согласных звуков (б-п, в-ф, г-к, д-т, з-с, ж-ш) и происходит в двух слабых позициях, а именно:  

Это неправда. Ц, Щ, Ч благополучно себе озвончаются на стыках слов.

И не только на стыках:  Зальцбург [зал'дзбурк], матчбол [маджбол], вещдок [веж'ж'док]/[ве'ж'д'ж'док]/[ве'ш'ж'док] (тут спорный случай, как и говорил).

Comment: Может быть, и озвончаются, но такие варианты стоит выделять особо, чтобы они не усложняли общую картину. Звонкие  Ц, Ч, Щ не относятся к фонетическому (фонемному)составу языка, слова такие встречаются редко, в школьной фонетике они вряд ли рассматриваются. А когда весь материал дается в одной плоскости (основной и вспомогательный, интегралы и правила сложения для начальной школы), то разобраться сложно.

Answer (score 0):

Здесь  есть  интересность - когда  я  читаю  не  произнося  слова  ( тот  же  берег ),  редукция  может  мной  не  ощущаться.  То  есть,  я  как  бы  слышу  "г" в  конце  слова.  Когда  я  читаю  текст  вслух  редукция,  как  мне  кажется,  ощущается  слабее.  Когда  я  просто  разговариваю  -  все  фонетические  законы   работают  как  положено.  Получается,  что,  если  не  знать  как  ведут  себя  звуки,  при  прочтении  без  произношения  легко  ошибиться.

Comment: Я не очень понял конечный вывод насчет "легко ошибиться", но вообще вопрос "внутреннего слуха", т.е. произношения "про себе" читаемого или воспроизводимого на письме текста очень непростой. Возможно, разные люди делают это по-разному. Кто-то, возможно, буквально произносит - от мозга идут психомоторные команды, которые просто не реализуются в полном объеме, кто-то ограничивается зрительным восприятием.   
Если так, т.е. есть разница в "подходах", то и выводы будут разные для этих двух (как минимум) групп.

Comment: Легко  ошибиться - это я о авторе вопроса.  Ответ  я  строил  на  собственном  восприятии,  т.к.  никаких  изысканий  по  этому  вопросу  я  не  проводил.  Но  можно  предположить,  что  не  все  знакомы  с  транскрипцией,  даже  на  этом  форуме.  Я  тоже  не  понял,  что  именно  вы  не  поняли.  По-моему,  вы  всё  поняли  как  надо.

Answer (score 0):

помогите разобраться со словом "КАЛЬМАР". В задании пробного регионального экзамена в 4 классе в разделе  русский язык был такой вопрос: В каком слове  **все согласные  звуки  звонкие** и даны варианты ответов - устрица, песчинка, кальмар, щупальце. Слово кальмар указано как верный ответ. Я поспорила, но меня слушать не стали. Правда ли, что в слове кальмар все согласные звуки звонкие?

Comment: Конечно, неправильно. В слове "кальмар" буква "к" обозначает глухой согласный звук "к"